# Resizing table based on content

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating a table dynamically using handlebars. My table can be any size between 1x1 to 10000x10.

How do I make a table that 'resizes' according to the content? Does this have to use javascript, or can it be achieved with CSS?

Thanks

Comment: I would use Javascript/jQuery to dynamically size the table based on the number of cells in a given direction. Haven't tried much with dynamically resizing tables using CSS alone.

Comment: can you give some guidance on how?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.flexigrid.info/